# How can a member function or an accessor know whether it's called by the watch window?

Tags: winforms, debugging, watch

I have a property CanClose that handles the question "Save modified DOC?" and returns true or false. Inside this property, if the DOC has been modified, the user is asked whether to close anyway, to save and then close or to abort (not to close). I put this property in the watch window and many dialogs are opened by the watch window. How can I understand whether the property is called by the watch window and thus skip the dialog?

```
    private bool CanClose
    {
        get
        {
            if(IsModified)
            {
                switch(MyMessageBox.AskYesNoCancelQuestion(this, "$ProgramModifiedQuestion", DialogResult.Yes))
                {
                    case DialogResult.No:
                        return true;
                    case DialogResult.Yes:
                        _saveToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
                        return true;
                    default: // Cancel
                        return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
```

By the way, in this case I bypassed the problem by *watching* the IsModified property that in effect is what interests me, but since this situation can occour in other contests too, I'd like to find a definitive solution.

Comment: _How can I understand whether the property is called by the watch window and thus skip the dialog?_ I don't think you can, unfortunately.

Comment: To make sure the property is called properly, you may want to make your application more unit-testable and use unit-tests. For example, you may want to inject that piece of behavior which is asking a question. Then when unit-testing, you can inject a dummy (mock) implementation which doesn't ask question.

Comment: As another option, you can introduce a setting to turn dialog windows on or off.